# Deprecated jQuery pseudo selectors and on() event handler

Tags: jquery, events

Right now, I've seen, that some pseudo selectors are deprecated as of jQuery 3.4, for example the [:last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector. Currently, I'm using these selectors to attach event handlers, like:

```
$('#my-table').on('click', '.btn:last', function (e) {
    // ...
});
```

I need this style of event handling, because I'm adding rows dynamically on runtime and don't want to add a separate event handler for each row that is added.

Documentation states, that I should use `last()` instead of `:last` now. But how to use this in `on()` handlers like above?

Comment: _"Because :last is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:last` **cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method**. To achieve the best performance when using :last to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use `.filter(":last")`"_ - "Your" `:last` is not used to query the DOM. It's only used to check if the event target matches that selector. You don't have to change anything.

Comment: I don't think so. Doc says "As of jQuery 3.4, the :last pseudo-class is deprecated. Remove it from your selectors and filter the results later using .last()." So it is *deprecated*.

Comment: Deprecated when selecting elements from the DOM. But you only "filter" the current selection (which is the event target). So you do exactly what the documentation says: "remove it from the selector" (it was never part of it) and "filter the results later" (the "delegation" part of your event delegation setup).

Comment: I'm not convinced by the above argument.  jQuery pages state *"remove it from your selectors"* (for all `createPositionalPseudo` calls) and the `.on` page also clearly states:   `.on(events, selector, ...` - so the `.btn:last` is clearly a "selector".  There's no mention on the jquery pages that it's "only when selecting elements from the DOM" rather than "filtering results".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest would be to just add a class to the button.

```
HTML:
<table id="my-table> 
  [...] 
  <button class="btn-last">Click</button> 
  [...] 
</table>

JS:
$('#my-table').on('click', '.btn-last', function (e) {
    // ...
});
```

Depending on your HTML you can also use last-child (maybe something like `td:last-child .btn`

```
$('#my-table').on('click', '.btn:last-child', function (e) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: `.btn:last-child` would return *every* button in the scenario of `<td><button></td>`  
- `tbody tr:last-child .btn` might be ok (assuming #my-table is a `<table>`)

Comment: Good point! Maybe `tr .btn:last-child` to select every last button of every row. But that's all speculation, OP can adjust accordingly to their need